# wp-admin on redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Everything was fine until I changed the parked domain. I changed the values of site url and home in wp_options table to my new domain name. Site works fine but I can not log in to admin dashboard.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

wp-login.php permissions are set to 775.

Comment: I will suggest you to check your server error log.

Comment: I have also removed .htaccess file. Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only DB update is not enough, you need to add below two lines to your `wp-config.php` like;

```
define('WP_HOME','http://new_domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://new_domain.com');
```

**Edit:** Also, be sure that your new folder structures are readable

Comment: Didn't work. I think if I have already changed the value of site url and home from the database, I do not need to do this.

Comment: Also do not forget it exists `www` or not

Comment: Yes I have updated new_domain with mine.

What do you mean by "Also do not forget it exists www or not ".

Comment: your domain is `www.new_domain.com` or `new_domain.com` . Is there any demo url I can have a look?

Comment: www.gogreentrading.com this is the site actually. Will remove it after you see it.

Comment: No it is wrong, you need to put `gogreentrading.com` in home url and site url

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48570/discussion-between-huseyin-babal-and-umair-khan-jadoon)